# How to check trigger action working for a table? How do I know its DISABLED/ENABLED?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

Is there any query to check this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you cannot just see the effect of the database trigger (it will be doing something, assigning field value, updating additional data, performing validation, etc.) you can use 4GL Client logging:

```
LOG-MANAGER:LOGFILE-NAME = "c:\temp\client.log".
LOG-MANAGER:LOG-ENTRY-TYPES = "4gltrace:5,4glmessages".
LOG-MANAGER:CLEAR-LOG ().

/* this will execute the schema create trigger */
CREATE Customer.

UNDO.
```

This will show that it's returning from the DB trigger in the logfile:

```
[22/01/17@11:49:42.013+0100] P-158784 T-160248 3 4GL 4GLTRACE       Return from Main Block "Customer" [sports2000trgs/crcust.p]
```

So it must have been executed.

Comment: Thanks @Mike Fechner.. What about modify/update/delete records? any why is there UNDO?

Comment: 4GLTrace should list _all_ triggers - regardless of the operation.

Comment: The UNDO is there just that I don't leave an empty record in my database.